# Time from the change of variable in useSelector and triggering useEffect takes too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using a `useSelector` in redux to save a variable. For example, in this case a variable called `inFocus`. This variable contains an array of objects. When this variable is updated (objects are being inserted into the array), it should trigger a `useEffect` which should execute a certain function. However, this trigger takes a very long time (up to 6000ms), making the app looks laggy. How can I improve on this?

The code:

```js
function setItemOcrInFocus() {
    if (selections && selections.clicks) {
      const clicks = selections.clicks.filter(
        (c) =>
          c?.selectedItem === item.id || c?.selectedItemIndex === item.index
      );

      if (clicks.length > 0) {
        dispatch({
          type: SET_STATE,
          payload: {
            inFocus: clicks,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  }

return (
    <Component onMouseEnter={() => setItemOcrInFocus()} />
)
```

**Component.js**

```js
function Component() {
    const [inFocus] = useSelector((state) => [
        state.item.inFocus,
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // execute a function here
    }, [inFocus])
}
```

The function `setItemOcrInFocus` is triggered when a specific component is being hovered over.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What exactly is eating up this 6000ms of time? Can you edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using?

Comment: @DrewReese I believe it is a delay where after `inFocus` is updated, it takes 6000ms before useEffect is triggered. I have slightly updated the code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you running some asynchronous logic somewhere? Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but your selector should be simply `const inFocus = useSelector((state) => state.item.inFocus);`, otherwise it will make your component rerender at every single state change.